# determine whether a circle intersects a county boundary in postGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon

I'm using PostGIS 2.0.1 and need to determine whether a circle (center + radius) intersects a county boundary (polygon).

The query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.id) FROM siteareas_poly sa, userlocations ul, 
            clienttypes ct INNER JOIN users_clienttypes uct on ct.id = uct.clienttype_id 
            INNER JOIN users u on uct.user_id = u.id 
            WHERE sa.id = 'concord' and ct.id = 2 
            AND ul.geog_lnglat is not null
            AND  ST_Intersects(st_exteriorring(sa.boundary), ST_BUFFER(ul.geog_lnglat,ul.radius_km * 1000)::geometry)
```

where the ul.geog_lnglat is a

```
geography(Point,4326)
```

and the sa.boundary is

```
geometry
```

I've tried a few variations on this and always gotten no results, when I expect to get at least one, as I have a row in userlocations that lies in that county (by zip lookup).

Am I making any glaring errors in my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ST_DWithin](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html). You will need to convert both to either planer `geometry` or `geography` types.

For example, to use ST_DWithin on `geography` inputs:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
  AND ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(sa.boundary, 4326)::geography,
                 ul.geog_lnglat,
                 ul.radius_km * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - I hadn't noticed the alternate parameters for ST_DWithin(). I tried your suggestion but got ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type - what should I be looking for?

Comment: Shifted coordinates?

Comment: @TomL I'm guessing the spatial reference (SRID) for your `sa.boundary` is not WGS84 Long/Lat, so you need to transform it; see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again - this answer has actually helped me think more clearly about the geometry of the question. Of course it's just a question of the point being within radius distance of the geometry - no need for a circle to be drawn.